# clear div float css property

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery ui dialog component where the dialog button is aligned to the right. The reason is because of the following property that gets set automatically.

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset {
    float: right;
}
```

If I clear this float: right property, the alignment looks fine. I tried it through Firebug. How do I clear this CSS property from my CSS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the property. This should work.

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset {
    float: none !important;
}
```

To avoid `!important` you can try add this CSS (your custom css file) after the css of the Jquery UI. The load order is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset {
    float: none;
}
```